# OpenCV determine what two hue values would best represent an image

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to determine what 2 hue values would best represent an image using OpenCV in a Python 3 script.
So far I have been able to access the hue channel and display its hue histogram:
[image]

As you can see there are basically pixels of 2 different hues, Beige and Green.

I have gained access to the hue channel as follows:

```html
hsv = cv.cvtColor( self.img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV )
hue,sat,val = cv.split(hsv)
```

What is the most efficient way to operate on the hue channel to determine what two hue values would best represent the image?

Edit #1 original image requested:
[image]

Edit #2 Almost there but still need help:

I have cobbled together some code to use OpenCV kmeans to convert images to 2 colors:

```html
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import sys

img = cv2.imread('3.JPG')
cv2.imshow('Original',img)
print (sys.version)
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("Python 3 or a more recent version is required.")

def redo():
    Z = img.reshape((-1,3))
    # convert to np.float32
    Z = np.float32(Z)
    # define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    K = 2
    start_time = time.time()
    ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Elapsed time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))
    # Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
    center = np.uint8(center)
    res = center[label.flatten()]
    res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))
    cv2.imshow('Converted',res2)    

while(1):
    ch = cv2.waitKey(50)
    if ch == 27:
        break
    if ch == ord(' '):
        redo()
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Still needed:

1. I really don't want to convert back into uint8, and make original image as 2 colors.  I would like to know the Hue value of those two colors.  How do I get these 2 values from the kmeans output parameters?
2. Is there a way to reduce the time to convert using kmeans? kmeans is taking 8.6 seconds to convert to 2 colors using Python 3 script on my Raspberry Pi Zero.  The conversion to 2 colors in Gimp is almost instantaneous (I know it is different processor but 8.6 seconds on Pi Zero is unusable for my purposes, maybe 1 second is OK).  I am just a novice but to me it looks like this kmeans code is acting on all RGB pixels when I just want the act on Hue, so could I not have kmeans act just on Hue and cut time considerably (doing that is a little beyond my abilities at this point tho).

Here is the 3.JPG image that takes 8.6 seconds:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the two most dominant colors? Check this [page](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/dominant-color/).

Comment: Wow, that hit the nail on the head, thanks, I will try to implement it.

Comment: Do you have the original image please?

Comment: Just added original image to question..

Comment: I'm going to look into this, but if you're on a pi, why not check out C? It'll be much faster.

Comment: Ouch :), I am just starting to get the hang of this Python scripting of OpenCV, I will check it out tho, thanks.

Comment: Do you have experience with C? If not, I can also look into writing something up for you on that front.

Comment: Just enough experience to get me in trouble. This is just a part of my grass/hard surface edge detection algorithm which I need so I can build my 54" wide pressure washing robot which will clean my 2500 feet of edge and 24000 ft^2 of  surface (plus tennis court)  while I supervise from my iPhone on wifi while I watch TV on my couch.  I have been playing with a bunch of images in Gimp and have a good idea what I need to do for my situational algorithm. It will only go a few in/sec so as long as i analyse a pic every few seconds I'm ok, but not 8.6 sec for just a part of routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tackled a few of the things you mentioned in you post.

1. You shouldn't need to cast back to uint8. Center is an array of size (2,3), where the rows are your center points (e.i. hues) and the columns are the BGR values of each hue.
2. I have switched to Scipy KMeans2 instead of using OpenCVs implementation. It seems to be about 3x faster on the same image as OpenCV.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, kmeans2
   import time, sys, cv2

   img = cv2.imread('3.jpg')                                                                                                                              
   print (sys.version)                                                                                                                                    
   if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
       raise Exception("Python 3 or a more recent version is required.")

   def redo():                                                                                                                                            
       Z = img.reshape((-1,3))                                                                                                                            
       Z = np.float32(Z)                                                                                                 

       # define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()                                                                                        
       criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)                                                                           
       K = 2                                                                                                                                              
       start_time = time.time()                                                                                                                           
       ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)                                                                        
       end_time = time.time()                                                                                                                             
       print("Elapsed cv2 time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))                                                                                 
       print("center")                                                                                                                                    
       print(center)                                                                                                                                      

       start_time = time.time()                                                                                                                           
       spcenter, splabel = kmeans2(Z,K,10,1,'points','warn',False)                                                                                        
       end_time = time.time()                                                                                                                             
       print("Elapsed scipy time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))                                                                               
       print("center")                                                                                                                                    
       print(spcenter)                                                                                                                                    

       print("diff")                                                                                                                                      
       check = np.abs(spcenter[0][0]-center[0][0])                                                                                                        
       checkflip = np.abs(spcenter[0][0]-center[1][0])                                                                                                    
       if (check < checkflip):                                                                                                                            
           print(np.abs(spcenter-center))                                                                                                                 
       else:                                                                                                                                              
           print("labels are flipped, has no effect on data")                                                                                             
           print(np.abs(spcenter-np.roll(center,1,0)))                                                                                                    

       # Now convert back into uint8, and make original image                                                                                             
       #center = np.uint8(center)                                                                                                                         
       res = spcenter[splabel.flatten()]
       res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))                                                                                                                    
       cv2.imwrite('converted.jpg',res2)                                                                                                                  

   redo()
   ```

You may not be able to do much better than whatever timing this code gives you. You could try shrinking the images if that works for your solution. It will result in faster processing.

Another solution, like I mentioned, is moving to a faster language such as C. I could try my hand at it, but I'm not sure what other code you are using and if it would work. Let me know if you want to go down this path.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! Kept getting 'NoneType' error until I put my While back in.  I get 3.9 secs with Scipy, strangely I tried an sklearn kmeans, but it was about 5X slower so I gave up looking for a better kmeans.  I will definitely work on smaller images now that I know I am so limited in processor abilities.

Comment: Might take you up on C code if I can't make a complete algorithm fast enough.  I learned much from your code (shows what a Python... newbie I am :)

Comment: Strange, when I view the Spicy converted image that was written to disk with an image viewer, it shows as expected, BUT when I add a cv2.imshow of it back in code, the imshow window shows it as all white pixels, any ideas on that?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the uint8 cast and/or flipping.

Comment: So, if you ever want to see either converted image with imshow, you have to use the uint8 cast before saving. P.S it looks like I might be able to use images as low as 60x80 for my purposes, which take only ~0.2 secs, yeah

Comment: Strangely, at that size the Cv2 conversion is faster at 0.15 sec, go figure.

Comment: If anyone is interested I have begun another question to help me finish my procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193713/opencv-python-script-from-gimp-procedure) .